# Can you isolate a system from conduction and convection, but not radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can you create a 'box' that isolates the inside from conduction and convection, but lets infrared and visible light pass?

Comment: Make it a vacuum system...

Comment: What do you mean by 'isolating the inside from convection'? I can't visualize that. Do you mean to say that heat transfer across the particles in the box cannot take place due to convection? Because that's pretty different from the corresponding idea of stopping the entry of energy into the system due to conduction from bodies in the surroundings.

Comment: yeah I was picturing a vacuum system made of a material that has a bandgap which allows most radiation trough. Thus stopping all non radiative heat from entering. What material am I looking for design? is I possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like a Dewar or Thermos bottle?

[image]

They usually have silvered glass to reduce heat transfer by radiation, but you could omit or remove that to let as much radiation through as you'd like.

[image]

The long neck is to support the weight, while greatly reducing conduction along it.  You'll also sometimes see baffles inside the neck to reduce the possibility of convection there too.

Comment: Yes, this is what i had in mind. If i place a sphere coated with reflective material inside this dewar, would the sphere cool down? It would reflect IR and visible light. So that you can place this dewar directly under sunlight and it would reflext all inconing radiation and emit radiation itself and cool down. Basically a sky radiative cooling system that is thermally isolated. Would this work?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. This is how solar heat collectors work. You surround the thing you wish to heat with double-paned glass windows. Visible and (some) IR go through the glass by radiation, and the glass blocks conduction and convection losses.

Please note that when the object inside the glass box gets hot enough, it will begin to re-radiate in the infrared, and if the glass used in the construction of the box happens to be transparent to IR then you'll start to lose some of the heat that you have collected. This means that for best performance, the glass itself has to be chosen to minimize this. The tradeoff then is that if the glass blocks IR losses, it also blocks incoming IR from outside.

The IR re-radiation rate scales strongly with the temperature of the hot object (as T^4) so if the temperature rise is moderate and not extreme, then those losses will not prevent this technique from working.

Comment: If instead you do a cooling system that works on the same principles, but the object inside reflects all visible and IR and emits its iwn infrared like you said. Would this work to cool itself down? And what would the limits be? Im guessing one issue would be finding a marerial that reflects all infrared but also manages to emitt it.

Comment: there is a number called the a-e ratio which is the ratio of the thermal absorbtivity to the emissivity for a given substance. In the ideal case (described by the physics of blackbody radiation) , a = e but in practice this is not always true. This ratio is a common figure of merit for solar heat collector materials and I recommend you search on it to find more about how it works. regarding refrigeration schemes you'd need something that emits everything (e is very  big) and absorbs nothing (a is nearly zero) and such materials do not exist in practice.

Comment: Ok thank you, ive looked up kirchhoff's law of thermal radiation, and it states that in thermal equilibrium emissivity equals absorbivity.  However maybe this is a function of wavelength: emission at wavelength(a)=absorption at wavelength(a). Maybe you can have a material that has high reflectivity of the wavelengths its exposed to, but emitts at a different wavelength ( which im guessing is a function of its temperature).

Comment: Much research was done in the 1970s and 80s looking for materials that had high absorbtivity and low emissivity. it's a hard problem- one of the promising approaches involved treating the surface of a material to get that effect and one of the results was something called "black chrome" (a du pont patent), a chrome plating process which absorbed well and re-radiated poorly- have you heard of it?

Comment: found something on 'black chrome' but it seems to be the opposite process. Not sure I completely understand the thermodynamic equilibrium considerations either.  The equilibrium condition should be only in the case that body A can absorb radiation from body B, any surface which is invisible to the specific wavelength produced by B will not progress towards equilibrium.

Comment: I think the key here is that the re-radiation spectrum is different from the absorption spectrum. you should be able to find references to papers on this topic in the solar energy collection literature.